# Determine solutions for an absolute value equation

Tags: absolute-value

I have 2 euqations that looks very similar, and here are my stpes： 
First one:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
3|x-1|-2 & = & 10 \\
3|x-1| & = & 12 \\
|x-1| & = & 4 \\
x-1 & = & \pm4
\end{eqnarray}
$$ 
Second one:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
|x+1|-5 & = & 3x \\
|x+1| & = & 3x+5 \\
x+1 & = & \pm(3x+5)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
I was told that my second solution was wrong becasue there was supposed to be only one solution for the second equation. What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|x|=y$ if and only if  $x= y $ or $x=-y$. We have to check which one (or both)holds.

In this case, from $|x+1|=3x+5$, we require that $3x+5\ge 0$.

---

$x+1=3x+5$ or $x+1=-3x-5$.

$2x=-4$ or $4x=-6$

$x=-2$ or $x=-\frac32$.

We can reject the first solution by checking $3x+5\ge 0$ is violated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but -2 and -3/2 are both less than 0, why the first solution is wrong, not both?

Comment: $3(-2)+5=-1 < 0$ but $3(-3/2)+5=0.5>0$.